# Is it common the performance in validation set being lower than the performance in test set during the training of a classifier?

Tags: neural-networks, train-test-split

I'm evaluating some settings for using graph convolutional networks for image classification.

- I'm using train/validation/test split of 64%/16%/20%, and adopting
  5-fold cross-validation. That is, in each iteration of the
  cross-validation, I'm using one fold as the test set, and from the
  union of the remaining 4 folds, I'm considering 80% for training and
  20% for validation. The three splits are balanced (have the same
  number of instances for each class).
- I'm using early stopping for stopping the training when the
  validation loss does not improve.
- I'm collecting the f-measure and loss of train/validation/test during
  the training process.
- I'm evaluating the performance on MNIST, Fashion MNIST, CIFAR-10,
  CIFAR-100, and STL10 datasets.

In my settings, during training, I'm observing an intriguing phenomenon.

- The loss of train data is always lower than the loss of test data,
  and the loss of both is always lower than the loss of validation
  data.
- The f-measure of train data is always higher than the f-measure of
  test data, and the f-measure of both is always higher than the
  f-measure of validation data.

Is this common or expected? If this is unexpected, how to deal with this issue?

Comment: How exactly do you combine the train/validation/test split with k-fold cross-validation?

Comment: Cross-validation is for allowing a more robust evaluation of the model, on different parts of the original data. For each iteration, one fold is considered the test data and from the union of the remaining data I'm considering 80% for training and 20% for validation. The validation set is being used for the early stopping.